# How to group together self asserting Azure AD B2C fields on UI and give each group a name visually using Identity Experience Framework Custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm searching for a way to group together self asserting Azure AD B2C fields and give each group a name visually in UI using Identity Experience Framework Custom policy. The result should look like the following example:

- User Info:

  - First Name
  - Last Name
- Subject Info:

  - Serial Number
  - Subject Name

Maybe I should put fields in two separate Technical Profiles and then somehow unite them in the Orchestration?

Can't do that in CSS due to required localization.

I have found nothing related to this at https://learn.microsoft.com and https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/Documentation

And have not found any examples where fields are grouped in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't group the form fields; however, you can split the registration form so that you collect the user information in one page and the subject information in another page.

A working example of this split (or paginated) registration can be experienced at [the Wingtip Games site](https://wingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net/).

The custom policies for this can be found at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies.

Comment: Do you know anything about B2C roadmap? Microsoft Graph Support. Projects looks stale :(

Answer (score 0):

With IEF, you can define extra claimtypes

```
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimType Id="group1">
      <DataType>string</DataType>
      <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
    </ClaimType>
    <ClaimType Id="group2">
      <DataType>string</DataType>
      <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
    </ClaimType>
  </ClaimsSchema>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

and use it in between to divide different group of input controls.

```
<ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Input">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="group1" DefaultValue="Group 1"/>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="group2" DefaultValue="Group 2"/>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="group1"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="group2" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
```

For the above ClaimType, it will be rendered on the page as:

```
<p id="group1">Group 1</p>
<p id="group2">Group 2</p>
```

Once you find the expected claim is rendered, you can then define your own css reposition it to have it look like what you proposed. You can also have it localized by doing Language Customization in policy as well as on Azure Portal.

[image]